# App Crashes before it even starts... i am using listview to open/call a fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, crash

I have a list view in MainActivity
there is a imageButton in each item row.....
when that Imagebutton is clicked a fragment should be shown.....

```
//main activity public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    ListView list;
    Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this, memTitles, images, memeDescriptions);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    } }
```

//list adapter class from which fragment is called

```
class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    ListAdapter(Context c, String[] titles, int imgs[], String[] desc) {

    }
//extra details are omitted from this code 
    @Override
    public View getView(final int postion, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
        ImageButton myImage = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        myImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String data;
                SharedPreferences pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("file", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                data = pref.getString("pos" + postion, "NOTHING");
                Fragment_display fr = new Fragment_display ();
                Bundle bundle  =  new Bundle();
                FragmentManager fm = ((Activity)context).getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                bundle.putString("value", data);
                fr.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fr);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        return row;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false" />
    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11.Fragment_display"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/listView"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment_Display..... this fragment displays data send to it

```
public class Fragment_display extends Fragment {

    TextView textView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String valueData= getArguments().getString("value");
        View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container,false);
        textView = (TextView) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText(valueData);
        return myInflatedView;
    }
}
```

fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffff00">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

logcat shows:

```
11-17 19:12:18.051  26694-26694/? E/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file
11-17 19:12:18.051  26694-26694/? E/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , loading version is VE=SEPF_GT-I9505_4.3_0024
11-17 19:12:18.051  26694-26694/? E/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
11-17 19:12:18.051  26694-26694/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
11-17 19:12:18.161  26694-26694/com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
11-17 19:12:18.161  26694-26694/com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
11-17 19:12:18.161  26694-26694/com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14061: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
11-17 19:12:18.161  26694-26694/com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11 D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
11-17 19:12:18.161  26694-26694/com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
11-17 19:12:18.161  26694-26694/com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14065: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
11-17 19:12:18.161  26694-26694/com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11 D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
11-17 19:12:18.211  26694-26694/com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
11-17 19:12:18.211  26694-26694/com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 412: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
11-17 19:12:18.211  26694-26694/com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11 D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-17 19:12:18.211  26694-26694/com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
11-17 19:12:18.211  26694-26694/com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 434: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
11-17 19:12:18.211  26694-26694/com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11 D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-17 19:12:18.271  26694-26694/com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11 D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-17 19:12:18.321  26694-26694/com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
11-17 19:12:18.321  26694-26694/com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41953898)
11-17 19:12:18.381  26694-26694/com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11/com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11.Fragment_display.onCreateView(Fragment_display.java:24)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:879)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1053)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1155)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4966)
            at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:78)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.example.mishaal.mges_lab11.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-17 19:12:21.824  26694-26694/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 26694 SIG: 9
```

can anyone tell why it is crashing..... i have no idea, plz help

Comment: getArguments() could be null and you've called getArguments().getString("value"). Put a null check before you use it.

Comment: the fragment you put in layout can't get String valueData= getArguments().getString("value");

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in your fragment:

```
        String valueData= getArguments().getString("value");
        View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container,false);
        textView = (TextView) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            String valueData= getArguments().getString("value");
            textView.setText(valueData);
        }
        return myInflatedView;
```

Comment: It is not working....... I think that problem is my main activity's xml, where I've put fragment and list-view,,,,,, but i want to show fragment only when i click image button in any row of listview

Comment: i've also tried to put in single row's xml....... i doesn't work their as well.....  plz help, as i m totally new to android development

Comment: i've also tried to put fragment* in single row's xml....... i doesn't work their as well..... plz help, as i m totally new to android development